# VBA Excel to find searched tab in Internet explorer

Tags: excel, vba

Below code is working fine only one thing is missing is that the code doesn't go to the searched tab in IE.

```
With CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
    If .Count > 0 Then
        Set IE = .Item(0)
        Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
        For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
            On Error Resume Next
            my_url = objShell.Windows(x).document.Location
            If my_url Like Sheets("Transfer Agency").Range("AB1") & "*" Then
                Set IE = objShell.Windows(x)
                '**How to activate/select the searched tab in IE**
                Exit For
            Else
            End If
        Next
    Else
        Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        IE.Visible = True
        IE.navigate Sheets("Transfer Agency").Range("AB1"), CLng(2048)
        Set IE = Nothing
    End If
End With
```

Comment: While I am sure that it's possible to activate a tab in IE, I haven't figured it out myself (admittingly, I haven't placed much effort either) and it doesn't appear to be an easy task. Is tab activation absolutely necessary, or do you just need to reference the tab for automation? If you need it to be the active window for some reason I would personally just create a new IE instance for each "tab" and you can just make the window active.

Comment: The only reason I ask is because many people here find the need to `.Activate` or `.Select` every single worksheet or cell/range because they think it's necessary for their code to function properly - which is incorrect (and actually has the opposite effect because then they implicitly and erroneously use `ActiveSheet` instead of qualifying variables). I understand this is with IE automation - but I am just ensuring you don't have the same mindset. Automation doesn't require you to look at the object you're working with, but many feel they need to see it anyway.

Comment: I understood Davis, but I need to activate/ select the tab. Its simple, if the tab in range ("AB1") is open then select the tab else open the link in new tab.